# Resharper Custom Pattern to convert string concatination in particular function to string interpolation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I would like to replace all instances of string concatenation in our custom logging with string interpolation. Right now I know ReSharper has rules to convert string concatenation to interpolation, but it only works if the text is highlighted. I want to apply a custom pattern to look is a parameter is made solely by string concatenation, then change it to interpolation.

Can someone help me build up this custom pattern or let me know if there is a way to somewhat join patterns together

Comment: Awesome I hope someone responds soon to this question